# Vuejs load js file after routing

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue-router

I am building a single page app with vuejs router.
Router works well, but I want to load specific script after routing to a component.

Smth like:

```
const Mine = {
    template: ' <div>Another</div>',
    load_script: <script src="/static/script.js"></script>
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Now I have current block in html:

```
<div id="routing">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

And this is in js:

```
const Mine = {template: ' <div>Another</div>'}

const routes = [
    { path: '/mine', component: Mine },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#routing')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the script in the HTML template itself, as it is done to load any file from HTML, you can have following in your template:

```
const Mine = {
    template: '<div> \
                  <script src="/static/script.js"></script> \
                   <div>Another</div> \
               </div>',    
}
```

Comment: Smth strange happens to me. Even `const Bar = { template: '<div>First</div><div>Second</div>' }` is not working. Showing only `First` no presence of `Second`. Therefore only script executing from your example. Don't see `Another`

Comment: @Snobby Try wrapping everything inside the `template` block in a div, like this:  `const Bar = { template: '<div><div>First</div><div>Second</div></div>' }`

Comment: That thing with `div`'s inside `div` worked well, thanks. But this trick will not work with `script`. So `const Bar = { template: '<div><div>First</div><script>console.log("Hooray")</script></div>' }` is not working of course nor `const Bar = { template: '<div>First</div><script>console.log("Hooray")</script>' }` Only first tag executes.

Comment: This thread seems to suggest that Vue strips out <script> tags from templates (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/467).